# Showing inequality of probabilty generating functions with the mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, derivatives

Let $Z_n$ be a nonnegative discrete random variable (Galton-Watson Process in this case). I need to show that:

$$\frac{f(\phi_{n}(\frac{u}{m}))-f(\phi_{n-1}(\frac{u}{m}))}{u} \le \frac{\phi_{n}(\frac{u}{m})-\phi_{n-1}(\frac{u}{m})}{\frac{u}{m}}  $$

where f is the probability generating function of $Z_n$, $1<E(Z_1) = m<\infty$, $u > 0$, $0\le\phi_n(u) = E(e^{-uZ_nm^{-n}})\le 1$ and $\phi_{n+1}(u)=f(\phi_n(\frac{u}{m}))$.

Write $a=\phi_{n-1}(\frac{u}{m})$ and $b=\phi_{n}(\frac{u}{m})$.
So I know that there exists a $x_0\in (a,b)\subsetneq [0,1]$ such that
$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = f'(x_0)
\\\Leftrightarrow
 f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(x_0) \le m(b-a)f'(x_0)$$
I know that $f(x)\le 1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ but $f'(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty p_jjx^{j-1}$ so i think that $f'(x)$ can be $\ge1$ because $j\in \mathbb{N}$ if i'm not mistaken. So where am I wrong here ?

Comment: I think you need the condition that the mean number of offspring is $\leq 1$ for the inequality to be true.

Comment: It is from the book Branching Processes by Ney and Athreya page 27 and in this case we consider the supercritical case i.e. $E(Z_1)=m>1$. https://books.google.de/books?id=WkXpDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA24&hl=de&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I made a mistake in the inequality so I edited it but I can't seem to find the answer. Another way to show the inequality is to show $f'(x_0)\le m$ which is not true either.

Comment: $f'(x)$ is increasing, so $f'(x_0) \leq f'(1)=m$.

Comment: Oh thats right! For some reason I thought f'(0) = m. Thank you.